# Find the source of Angular's "Unknown Provider" error in the stack trace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I get this error sometimes. I understand what it means. For a large project, it can be difficult to find the file and line of code that is causing the issue. The console stack trace goes back through angular code but never traces back up to the application where the issue is originating.

```
Error: Unknown provider: ProductProvider <- Product
```

Is there a process, browser plugin, or code library that will allow me to trace this error back to the file or line of code that causes it?

Comment: The error doesnt happen inside a function you defined,but inside angular injector,once Angular tries to resolve services. So nope. You need to grep your file for Product service,that's all you can do.

Comment: Yes, that's where it's coming from. But maybe an extension to `$provider` could add another layer of introspection, or maybe someone has done this as some kind of plugin. Optimistic, I know. :) I'm doe-eyed and hopeful like the Bambi of angular.